# Nginx won't serve web application

Tags: nginx, centos

I can't get Nginx to redirect to my web application on GCP. The platform is Centos 7

Below is what I have under /etc/nginx

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   62 Jan 17 20:22 conf.d
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1077 Nov  1 02:02 fastcgi.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1077 Nov  1 02:02 fastcgi.conf.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1007 Nov  1 02:02 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1007 Nov  1 02:02 fastcgi_params.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2837 Nov  1 02:02 koi-utf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2223 Nov  1 02:02 koi-win
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5231 Nov  1 02:02 mime.types
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5231 Nov  1 02:02 mime.types.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2455 Nov  1 02:02 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2656 Nov  1 02:02 nginx.conf.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  636 Nov  1 02:02 scgi_params
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  636 Nov  1 02:02 scgi_params.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  664 Nov  1 02:02 uwsgi_params
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  664 Nov  1 02:02 uwsgi_params.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3610 Nov  1 02:02 win-utf
```

I haven't changed the nginx.conf file. Instead I have created /etc/nginx/conf.d/opc.conf. And below is what is inside.

```
server {

  server_name 14.72.135.78;

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://10.128.0.2:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

When I do

```
 netstat -tnl
```

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6010            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6011            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6012            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6014            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 10.128.0.2:8080         :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6010                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6011                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6012                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6014                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

EDIT:

When I do curl http://10.128.0.2:8080, the result is empt. May this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `listen` directive here:

```
server {
  listen 14.72.135.78:80;
  server_name 14.72.135.78;

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://10.128.0.2:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

[Documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, didn't work :(

Comment: erver {
  listen      14.72.135.78:80;
  server_name 14.72.135.78;

  location /opc {
    proxy_pass http://10.128.0.2:8080;
  }
}

Comment: @ÇağlarYıldız Check logs, what's the error? Also you need to access the service via `14.72.135.78`, not `localhost` and not domain.

Comment: I thought the problem was the SELinux, so I have disabled it. Also there is no error, all that I get is the access log.